# Pre-Islamic Arabic dust worship?

Tags: arabic, middle-east

The Talmud in [Bava Metzia 86b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Metzia.86b.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says on the story of Abraham and the three angels (emphasis mine):

> "The Gemara continues its analysis of the verse: “Let now a little water be fetched and wash your feet” ([Genesis 18:4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.18.4?lang=bi&aliyot=0)). Rabbi Yannai, son of Rabbi Yishmael, said that the guests said to Abraham: Are you suspicious that we are **Arabs who bow to the dust of their feet**?

Is there any evidence of a pre-Islamic Arabic worship of dust?

Comment: To me, this sounds more like a metaphor, rather than pertaining to actual worship of dust. It could be that it is conveying a sense of irony about what they worship.

Comment: @MatthewMartin at the very least it was interpreted as being literally so by one of the greatest medieval Jewish commentators, [Rashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi), in his [commentary on the verse](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rashi_on_Genesis.18.4.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). Of course, it could also be argued that Rashi simply took the talmud at face value, but it's equally possible that he had evidence to corroborate the literal understanding.

Comment: interesting. I did not know this.

Comment: To this day, Arabs literally worship by kneeling and then bowing their forehead down to the ground. Since they live(d) in the Arabian desert, the conclusion follows.

Comment: @Lucian are you suggesting that that's evidence in itself or that the Talmud reached a false conclusion about Muslims? The latter would be problematic, seeing as [Rabbi Yannai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbi_Yannai) lived a few centuries before the time of Mohammed. In fact, the majority of the Talmud was written before he was even born.